# Android Rellenar con decimales

Tags: java, android

Tengo un reporte donde muestro ciertos valores numericos que me llegan de un servicio x ,

mi problema en concreto es que si el numero es 5.10

el servicio me manda 5.1

Si yo mando 5.00 el servicio me trae 5

Pero si mando 5.23 si me llega 5.23 , lo que quiero hacer es :

que si llega 5.1 se complete con 5.10  , si llega con 5 que lo deje como 5.00 , pense en hacer esto con 2 IFS y preguntar la cantidad de caracteres y agregarle los 0 pero me parece poco eficaz o muy precario , existe alguna forma de realizar este proceso ?

```
 final ArrayList<MovimientoCuenta> items = new ArrayList<>();


int cantidad  = response.getMessageRS().getData().size();
                int iterador = 0 ;
                while(iterador<cantidad) {
                    MovimientoCuenta aux2 = new MovimientoCuenta(response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).getDST(),
                            "USD "+response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).getAMOUNT(), // este es el monto
                            response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).getCURRENCY(),
                            response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).getDATE(),""
                            ,response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).getREFERENCE(),"",
                            response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).getSIGN(),
                            response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).getNAME());
                    items.add(aux2);
                    iterador ++;
                }
```

Ya intente

```
DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("###.00");

       mount.setText(item.getMoneda() + " "+formater.format(Double.parseDouble(item.getMonto())));
```

Comment: El formato es "casi" correcto, debería ser DecimalFormat formater = 
 DecimalFormat("0.00");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizar una conversión a double a partir del String y aplicar un formato que aplique doble decimal `"0.00"`, ejemplo:

```
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
  String numeroString = "5.1";
  double num =  Double.parseDouble(numeroString);       
  System.out.println ("Resultado: " + df.format(num));
```

Tendrías como resultado:

```
"5.10"
```

---

Lo mismo para los demás valores:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    String numer = "5.1";
    double num =  Double.parseDouble(numer);        
    System.out.println ("Original: "+ numer + " Resultado: " + df.format(num));
    //Original: 5.1 Resultado: 5.10

    numer = "5.23";
    num =  Double.parseDouble(numer);       
    System.out.println ("Original: "+ numer + " Resultado: " + df.format(num));
    //Original: 5.23 Resultado: 5.23

    numer = "5";
    num =  Double.parseDouble(numer);
    System.out.println ("Original: "+ numer + " Resultado: " + df.format(num));
    //Original: 5 Resultado: 5.00
```

Aplicado a tu código Android:

```
 DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
 mount.setText(item.getMoneda() + " "+formater.format(Double.parseDouble(item.getMonto())));
```

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza el metodo [`String.format()`](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) para formatear el valor:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble("5.10"))); // 5.10
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble("5.23"))); // 5.23
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble("5.0")));  // 5.0
```

`%.2f` quiere decir lo siguiente:

```
% = Numero
2f = 2 numeros flotantes
```

Comment: System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble("5.0")));  // 5.0
 no deberia ser 5.10? solo un detalle , gracias por la mano Einer!